# In Java, is there a way to exit a method that will also exit all vertically nested methods?

Tags: java, methods, exit

I'm looking for some kind of statement or function that, when hit, will not only exit the current method (method 1), but all methods the current method is nested within (methods 2, 3, and 4), WITHOUT exiting the program (stops at run, I guess).

I'm hoping for an alternative to conditionally checking every instance in which method 1 is (or could be) called. Thanks!

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class ExitTest implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new ExitTest());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        method4();
    }
    
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("I want this line to hit.");
        // Looking for something here that exits all nested methods
    }
    
    public void method2() {
        method1();
        System.out.println("I don't want this line to hit.");
    }
    
    public void method3() {
        method2();
        System.out.println("I don't want this line to hit.");
    }
    
    public void method4() {
        method3();
        System.out.println("I don't want this line to hit.");
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Tell us what you're really trying to do, at a high level.

Comment: You can throw an exception and catch it in the run method. That is as close as you can get.

Comment: Well, how would the program know when to stop exiting methods? I assume you don't want to exit `run`, but how is `run` different from `method2`, `method3` etc?

Comment: This is pretty much the point of exceptions. Put `try{ method4(); } catch(RuntimeException e){ ...}` You can have it go as high up the stack as you like before you handle it, or handle and rethrow.

Answer (score 2):

Like everyone is saying, you can throw an exception in method1 and handle the exception in method 4 as below.

```
public class Main  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().run();
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Calling method 4");
        try {
            method4();
        }catch(Exception e){ }
        System.out.println("Return from method 4");
    }
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("I want this line to hit.");
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    public void method2() {
        method1();
        System.out.println("I don't want this line to hit.");
    }
    public void method3() {
        method2();
        System.out.println("I don't want this line to hit.");
    }
    public void method4() {
        method3();
        System.out.println("I don't want this line to hit.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Catch neither general "Exception" nor less general "RuntimeException". Create your own exception class for your use case!

Comment: Although the OP has been a bit vague. You probably should put throw clauses on the methods that will not handle the exceptions, that way it is explicit in the API.

Comment: And if threads are involved,  creating an UncaughtExceptionHandler can be quite useful.